# In Outlook how could I make a rule that would block the .co TLD but not .co.uk or .com

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules, tld

If you add a rule to block senders address which contains ".co"  Outlook will also block .co.uk & .com

This, I imagine, is because there is no way to specify 'end of string' to Outlook so that it knows to just look for .co and not for example, .co.uk

Also, there appears to be no way to specify "that but not this"  whereby you could e.g include ".co" but exclude ".co.uk" and ".com"

Comment: If you added separate rules to allow ".co.uk" and ".com", I wonder which rule wins.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I noticed that ".co" seems to be Colombia domain. And based on my research, I found a [thread](https://forums.bit-tech.net/index.php?threads/how-to-block-spam-in-outlook-from-co-but-not-com.278595/) mention that emails with ".co" will be blocked but emails with ".com" can be received normally after adding "co" to "Blocked Top-Level Domain List". It's suggested that you could try to do it:

1.Under **Home** tab > Click **Junk** icon > Click **Junk E-mail Options…**

[image]

2.Switch to **International** > Click **Blocked Top-Level Domain List** > select **CO (Colombia)**.

[image]

3.Click **Ok**.

Hope the above help!

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.